# option Groups in select boxes

Tags: groups, options

One of my fields is a channel in a select dropdown. Can I add option groups in

Jumpstart > CP > Home > Administration > Channel Fields >Edit Field ?

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not with the native select drop down, no. But, you can do it with the select field from [Pixel & Tonic's Field Pack](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/field-pack) add-on. [See the docs for details](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/fieldpack/fieldtypes/dropdown/config.html).

Comment: caveat: channel in a select dropdown (e.g. i'm guessing the option: Populate the menu from another channel field)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the option groups in combination with: *Populate the menu from another channel field*, then you would need to modify and customise a fieldtype. Something that makes a dropdown from a table, and modify the fieldtype to make option groups based on category, tags or whatever.

Some starting points to build a custom fieldtype of:

- [sp-table-select](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/sp-table-select)
- [query-field](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/query-field)
- [chosen-selects](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/chosen-selects)